# Rxjava2 - multi retrofit request and handle all exception

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I am new to Rxjava. It is so complex......

I need to handle a complex scenario, I want to know how to make it using Rxjava.

It's a logic about app start:

1. app start and `splash` page open
2. make http reqesut `check_update` to check if app need update.
3. if app has new version and must update, pop up a notice dialog with only one `update` button; if app has new version, but not must update, then pop up a dialog with 2 button(`update` and `ignore`); if no new version, go next.
4. no need to update, so we need to jump to `home` page or `login` page, according to current `auth_token` state.
5. read `auth_token` from sharedPreference. then call http request `check_auth` to check if it is valid or not. if valid, jump to `home` page; if not, jump to `login` page.

In this process, 2 http requests and lots of condition checks are involved. http request error also need to be handled, Can this process be written in one `Rxjava`?

I think I can do it in this way, but I am not sure if it is right.

```
mRetrofitService.checkUpdate(new CheckUpdateRequest("android", "0.0.1")) // check update request
            .compose(RxUtil.applyScheduler()) // scheduler
            .flatMap(RxUtil.applyFunction()) // handle the response.
            .flatMap((Function<CheckUpdateResponse, ObservableSource<?>>) checkUpdateResponse -> {
                int updateMode;
                if (checkUpdateResponse.isHas_new_version()) {
                    if (checkUpdateResponse.isForce_update()) {
                        updateMode = FORCE_UPDATE; // 1
                    } else {
                        updateMode = CHOOSE_UPDATE; // 2
                    }
                }  else {
                    updateMode = NO_UPDATE; // 0
                }
                return Observable.just(updateMode);
            })
            .flatMap(o -> {
                if (Integer.parseInt(o.toString()) == NO_UPDATE) {
                    return mRetrofitService.checkAuth();
                }
                return null; //what should I return for pop up dialog?
            })
            .flatMap(RxUtil.applyFunction())
            .subscribe(new Observer<CheckAuthResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(CheckAuthResponse checkAuthResponse) {
                    // valid
                    gotoHome();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    // should I handle pop here?
                    // should I handle auth invalid here?
                    // should I handle checkUpdate request error here?
                    // should I handle checkAuth here?
                    // how to distinguish these errors?
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            });
```

Am I right? And would you please answer my questions(comments in the code)?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation [onError](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observer.html#onError(java.lang.Throwable)) "Notifies the Observer that the Observable has experienced an error condition.". So this callback is not relevant to handle request errors.

I suggest you to use the [Response](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Response.html) class of retrofit to handle your differents cases.

For example you define your service like that :

```
@method(url)
Call<CheckAuthResponse> checkUpdate(...);
```

and in your rx workflow :

```
mRetrofitService.checkUpdate(new CheckUpdateRequest("android", "0.0.1")) // check update request
            .compose(RxUtil.applyScheduler()) // scheduler
            .flatMap(RxUtil.applyFunction()) // handle the response.
            .map((Function<Response<CheckUpdateResponse>, CheckUpdateResponse>) retrofitResponse -> {
                if ( retrofitResponce.code() == authInvalidCode ) {
                  //do something
                 } else if (...) {

                 }
                 return retrofitResponse.body()
            })
            .flatMap((Function<CheckUpdateResponse, ObservableSource<?>>) checkUpdateResponse -> {
                int updateMode;
                if (checkUpdateResponse.isHas_new_version()) {
                    if (checkUpdateResponse.isForce_update()) {
                        updateMode = FORCE_UPDATE; // 1
                    } else {
                        updateMode = CHOOSE_UPDATE; // 2
                    }
                }  else {
                    updateMode = NO_UPDATE; // 0
                }
                return Observable.just(updateMode);
            })
            .flatMap(o -> {
                if (Integer.parseInt(o.toString()) == NO_UPDATE) {
                    return mRetrofitService.checkAuth();
                }
                return null; //what should I return for pop up dialog?
            })
            .flatMap(RxUtil.applyFunction())
            .subscribe(new Observer<CheckAuthResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(CheckAuthResponse checkAuthResponse) {
                    // valid
                    gotoHome();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    // should I handle pop here?
                    // should I handle auth invalid here?
                    // should I handle checkUpdate request error here?
                    // should I handle checkAuth here?
                    // how to distinguish these errors?
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            });
```

Hope this helps;

Sorry for my english.

Comment: ` if ( retrofitResponce.code() == authInvalidCode ) {
                  //do something
 }`
It is run in schedule.io, so if I want to show a toast, it seems I can not make it here.

Comment: You can add before the map function observeOn( Androidscheduler.mainThread()) , an add observeOn(relevantScheduler) after if you want to do next operations in another thread.